# How to detect the side on which collision occured

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, game-development

This is my first post so I'm trying to make my problem as clear as possible. I'm making a game and I want to improve my collision detection. This is because I want to check what side is being hit and stop the player from moving past it without using something general like *if(collision(player, enemy)) player.x = enemy.x - player.w(width)* because if the player were to collide with the top it wouldn't keep the player on top.

In the code it checks if any one of the statements is true and then returns it but it doesn't tell me which statement was the one that was equal to true so I can stop the player from moving accordingly, if that makes sense. If you have a more efficient collision detection for me to use it would be greatly appreciated.

I've already tried to make a position variable to be equal to whatever side gets collided into and then stop the player from moving past it but it only works for the left side and won't let my player jump over the enemy or block.

```
function collision(object1, object2) {

       return !(
            object1.x > object2.x + object2.w  ||
            object1.x + object1.w < object2.x  ||
            object1.y > object2.y + object2.h  ||
            object1.y + object1.h < object2.y 
        )
}

//Only works for the left side

if(collision(player, enemy)) player.x = enemy.x - player.w
```

I expect it to be able to tell me what side is being collided into and then either stop the player from moving past/into it and for the player to be able to be on top of the block/enemy without just being pushed to the left.

Comment: Can you post more code to reproduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to calculate the distance between the x's and y's and also use the minimum distance that they could be colliding along each axis to find the depth along both axes. Then you can pick the smaller depth and move along that one. Here's an example:

```
if(collision(player, enemy)){
    // Most of this stuff would probably be good to keep stored inside the player
    // along side their x and y position. That way it doesn't have to be recalculated
    // every collision check
    var playerHalfW = player.w/2
    var playerHalfH = player.h/2
    var enemyHalfW = enemy.w/2
    var enemyHalfH = enemy.h/2
    var playerCenterX = player.x + player.w/2
    var playerCenterY = player.y + player.h/2
    var enemyCenterX = enemy.x + enemy.w/2
    var enemyCenterY = enemy.y + enemy.h/2

    // Calculate the distance between centers
    var diffX = playerCenterX - enemyCenterX
    var diffY = playerCenterY - enemyCenterY

    // Calculate the minimum distance to separate along X and Y
    var minXDist = playerHalfW + enemyHalfW
    var minYDist = playerHalfH + enemyHalfH

    // Calculate the depth of collision for both the X and Y axis
    var depthX = diffX > 0 ? minXDist - diffX : -minXDist - diffX
    var depthY = diffY > 0 ? minYDist - diffY : -minYDist - diffY

    // Now that you have the depth, you can pick the smaller depth and move
    // along that axis.
    if(depthX != 0 && depthY != 0){
      if(Math.abs(depthX) < Math.abs(depthY)){
        // Collision along the X axis. React accordingly
        if(depthX > 0){
            // Left side collision
        }
        else{
            // Right side collision
        }
      }
      else{
        // Collision along the Y axis.
        if(depthY > 0){
           // Top side collision
        }
        else{
           // Bottom side collision
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

### Working example

Here's a working example that you can play around with. Use the arrow keys to move the player around.

```js
player = {
  x: 9,
  y: 50,
  w: 100,
  h: 100
}
enemy = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  w: 100,
  h: 100
}
output = document.getElementById("collisionType");
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

function collision(object1, object2) {
  return !(
    object1.x > object2.x + object2.w ||
    object1.x + object1.w < object2.x ||
    object1.y > object2.y + object2.h ||
    object1.y + object1.h < object2.y
  )
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
  ctx.lineWidth = "5"
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.rect(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.rect(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.w, enemy.h);
  ctx.stroke();

}

function handleCollision() {
  if (collision(player, enemy)) {
    var playerHalfW = player.w / 2
    var playerHalfH = player.h / 2
    var enemyHalfW = enemy.w / 2
    var enemyHalfH = enemy.h / 2
    var playerCenterX = player.x + player.w / 2
    var playerCenterY = player.y + player.h / 2
    var enemyCenterX = enemy.x + enemy.w / 2
    var enemyCenterY = enemy.y + enemy.h / 2

    // Calculate the distance between centers
    var diffX = playerCenterX - enemyCenterX
    var diffY = playerCenterY - enemyCenterY

    // Calculate the minimum distance to separate along X and Y
    var minXDist = playerHalfW + enemyHalfW
    var minYDist = playerHalfH + enemyHalfH

    // Calculate the depth of collision for both the X and Y axis
    var depthX = diffX > 0 ? minXDist - diffX : -minXDist - diffX
    var depthY = diffY > 0 ? minYDist - diffY : -minYDist - diffY

    // Now that you have the depth, you can pick the smaller depth and move
    // along that axis.
    if (depthX != 0 && depthY != 0) {
      if (Math.abs(depthX) < Math.abs(depthY)) {
        // Collision along the X axis. React accordingly
        if (depthX > 0) {
          output.innerHTML = "left side collision"
        } else {
          output.innerHTML = "right side collision"
        }
      } else {
        // Collision along the Y axis.
        if (depthY > 0) {
          output.innerHTML = "top side collision"
        } else {
          output.innerHTML = "bottom side collision"
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = "No collision"
  }
}

keyStates = []

function handleKeys() {
  if (keyStates[39]) {
    player.x += 2 //Move right
  } else if (keyStates[37]) {
    player.x -= 2 //Move left
  }
  if (keyStates[38]) {
    player.y -= 2 //Move up
  }
  if (keyStates[40]) {
    player.y += 2 //Move down
  }
}

function main() {
  handleKeys();
  draw();
  handleCollision();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  keyStates[e.keyCode] = true
}

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  keyStates[e.keyCode] = false
}

main();
```

```html
<h2 id="collisionType"></h2>
<canvas id="canvas" width='300' height='300'></canvas>
```

### Reacting to the collision

Now that you know the side the collision happened on, it should be fairly trivial to decide how to react. It would be very similar to what you are currently doing for the left side just flip some signs around and change the axis.

### Other Considerations

- You may want to take into account your player's velocity (if it has one) otherwise the detection may fail.

  - If the player's velocity is too high, it might 'tunnel' through the enemy and no collision will be detected.
  - The player's movement can also look jittery if the velocity is not stopped upon collision
- Can your objects rotate or have more than 4 sides? If so, you'll probably want to use another method as described below.

[Here's a good answer to another post that talks in depth about collision engines](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26506)

### Other Methods

As for other collision detection methods, there's quite a few but one that comes to mind is [Separating Axis Theorem](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/) which is a little more complex than what you have but will work with more complex convex shapes and rotation. It also tells you the direction and distance needed to move to resolve the collision. [Here's a site](https://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) that has interactive examples and goes in-depth on the subject. It doesn't appear to give a full implementation but those can be found other places.

Comment: Honestly this is crazy. I didn't really think someone would be able to recreate my code with the very little context I gave and be able to solve my problem but you did! Pretty cool. It works. Thanks a lot, to you, and the editors. Guess this site was bound to have some very smart people, huh.

Comment: By the way shouldn't  _var enemyHalfW = player.w/2_ and  _var enemyHalfH = player.h/2_ equal _enemy.w/2_ and _enemy.h/2_